# MuleSoft Deployment Failed 3.9.0

Tags: mulesoft

I am running mule soft version 3.9.0 to deploy my application into Any platform cloud hub deployment when I am running build locally with maven command build got success.

Then I have created zip file package using "mvn clean package" command to deploy the package to the cloud hub, I am getting below error.

```
<mule xmlns:tls="http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/tls" xmlns:http="http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/http"
    xmlns:sfdc="http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/sfdc"
    xmlns="http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/core" xmlns:doc="http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/documentation"
    xmlns:spring="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/http http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/http/current/mule-http.xsd
http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/sfdc http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/sfdc/current/mule-sfdc.xsd
http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-current.xsd
http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/core http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/core/current/mule.xsd
http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/tls http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/tls/current/mule-tls.xsd">
```

Error

---

```
org.xml.sax.SAXParseException; lineNumber: 75; columnNumber: 219; cvc-complex-type.2.4.a: Invalid content was found starting with element 'sfdc:replay-streaming-channel'. One of '{"http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/core":annotations, "http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/core":description, "http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/core":abstract-message-source, "http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/core":abstract-inbound-endpoint, "http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/core":abstract-message-processor, "http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/core":abstract-outbound-endpoint, "http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/core":abstract-mixed-content-message-processor, "http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/core":response}' is expected.
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.util.ErrorHandlerWrapper.createSAXParseException(ErrorHandlerWrapper.java:203)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.util.ErrorHandlerWrapper.error(ErrorHandlerWrapper.java:134)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLErrorReporter.reportError(XMLErrorReporter.java:396)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLErrorReporter.reportError(XMLErrorReporter.java:327)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLErrorReporter.reportError(XMLErrorReporter.java:284)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.xs.XMLSchemaValidator$XSIErrorReporter.reportError(XMLSchemaValidator.java:453)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.xs.XMLSchemaValidator.reportSchemaError(XMLSchemaValidator.java:3231)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.xs.XMLSchemaValidator.handleStartElement(XMLSchemaValidator.java:1791)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.xs.XMLSchemaValidator.emptyElement(XMLSchemaValidator.java:761)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLNSDocumentScannerImpl.scanStartElement(XMLNSDocumentScannerImpl.java:351)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLDocumentFragmentScannerImpl$FragmentContentDriver.next(XMLDocumentFragmentScannerImpl.java:2784)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLDocumentScannerImpl.next(XMLDocumentScannerImpl.java:602)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLNSDocumentScannerImpl.next(XMLNSDocumentScannerImpl.java:112)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLDocumentFragmentScannerImpl.scanDocument(XMLDocumentFragmentScannerImpl.java:505)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.XML11Configuration.parse(XML11Configuration.java:842)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.XML11Configuration.parse(XML11Configuration.java:771)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.XMLParser.parse(XMLParser.java:141)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.DOMParser.parse(DOMParser.java:243)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.jaxp.DocumentBuilderImpl.parse(DocumentBuilderImpl.java:339)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.DefaultDocumentLoader.loadDocument(DefaultDocumentLoader.java:76)
    at org.mule.config.spring.MuleDocumentLoader.loadDocument(MuleDocumentLoader.java:91)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.XmlBeanDefinitionReader.doLoadDocument(XmlBeanDefinitionReader.java:429)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.XmlBeanDefinitionReader.doLoadBeanDefinitions(XmlBeanDefinitionReader.java:391)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.XmlBeanDefinitionReader.loadBeanDefinitions(XmlBeanDefinitionReader.java:336)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.XmlBeanDefinitionReader.loadBeanDefinitions(XmlBeanDefinitionReader.java:304)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanDefinitionReader.loadBeanDefinitions(AbstractBeanDefinitionReader.java:181)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanDefinitionReader.loadBeanDefinitions(AbstractBeanDefinitionReader.java:217)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.DefaultBeanDefinitionDocumentReader.importBeanDefinitionResource(DefaultBeanDefinitionDocumentReader.java:229)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.DefaultBeanDefinitionDocumentReader.parseDefaultElement(DefaultBeanDefinitionDocumentReader.java:186)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.DefaultBeanDefinitionDocumentReader.parseBeanDefinitions(DefaultBeanDefinitionDocumentReader.java:171)
    at org.mule.config.spring.MuleBeanDefinitionDocumentReader.parseBeanDefinitions(MuleBeanDefinitionDocumentReader.java:56)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.DefaultBeanDefinitionDocumentReader.doRegisterBeanDefinitions(DefaultBeanDefinitionDocumentReader.java:144)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.DefaultBeanDefinitionDocumentReader.registerBeanDefinitions(DefaultBeanDefinitionDocumentReader.java:100)
    at org.mule.config.spring.MuleHierarchicalBeanDefinitionParserDelegate.handleSpringElements(MuleHierarchicalBeanDefinitionParserDelegate.java:182)
    at org.mule.config.spring.MuleHierarchicalBeanDefinitionParserDelegate.parseCustomElement(MuleHierarchicalBeanDefinitionParserDelegate.java:81)
    at org.mule.config.spring.MuleHierarchicalBeanDefinitionParserDelegate.parseCustomElement(MuleHierarchicalBeanDefinitio... [truncated]
```

Can you someone please help to fix this issue, let me know if anything required.

Comment: The error message seems incomplete. Pleas paste the complete error. Stack traces are not required.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like the Salesforce connector dependency was not added to the POM, or the namespace declaration/schema location is missing at the top element of the XML configuration (example `<mule xmlsn:sfdc=... xsi:schemaLocation="..."`). Usually Anypoint Studio does that automatically but if you are editing manually the XML you need to do it yourself.

In the pom.xml the dependency should look like:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.mule.modules</groupId>
    <artifactId>mule-module-sfdc</artifactId>
    <version>8.9.2</version>
</dependency>
```

Comment: Hi Aled, Thanks for the quick response, in my pom file i have already added mule-salesforce-connector dependency with version 9.3.2. But how can i add the namespace declaration, which file i have use to add this.

Comment: You mean inside the configuration.xml file ?

Comment: Yes, the namespace in the Mule configuration XML where the flows are defined. The dependency should be in the pom.xml of the project.

Comment: I have added configuration.xml in above, can you please help me on this, i am new to this mulesoft, actually i am DevOps resources, i am trying to resolve this issue past one week

Comment: The <mule> element seems correct. Is the connector dependency in the pom? I'm adding an example to my answer. Please add to the question the snippet of the flow that uses the connector. It is line 75 of an XML file according to the error. Add a few lines above and below for context.

Answer (score 0):

Add the below to your pom.xml file, SFDC component needs to be included with app-maven-plugin. Only then it will be included in app/lib folder.

```
<plugin>
<groupId>org.mule.tools.maven</groupId>
<artifactId>mule-app-maven-plugin</artifactId>
<version>${mule.tools.version}</version>
<extensions>true</extensions>
<configuration>
    <copyToAppsDirectory>true</copyToAppsDirectory>
    <inclusions>
        <inclusion>
            <groupId>org.mule.modules</groupId>
            <artifactId>mule-module-sfdc</artifactId>
        </inclusion>
    </inclusions>
</configuration>
```